# How to test rake task callbacks

Tags: ruby, rspec

I create test code with rspec. I want to test callback is executed or not.
`task main: [:callback]` means run `callback` before `main`, doesn't it?

But my test failed. I looks like `callback` is not executed. Why?

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'rake'

RSpec.describe 'Rake::Task' do
  before(:all) do
    @rake = Rake::Application.new
    Rake.application = @rake
    Rake.application.rake_require('rspec_before', ["#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks"])
  end

  subject { @rake['rspec_before:main'].execute }

  it "expects run callback before main task" do
    expect{ subject }.to output(/Hello, world/).to_stdout
  end
end
```

My Rake task is below.

```
namespace :rspec_before do
  task :callback do
    @greeting = "Hello, world"
  end

  # case 1
  # In this case, `callback` is NOT executed in rspec
  # In console, `callback` is executed !!!!
  desc "main task"
  task main: [:callback] do
    puts @greeting
  end

  # case 2
  # In this case, `callback` is executed in rspec
  # task :main do
  #   Rake::Task['rspec_before:callback'].execute
  #   puts @greeting
  # end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not sure I would call `:callback` a *callback*, it's more of a *dependency*. A *callback* implies it happens after the main task is done, whereas when you do

```
task main: [:callback]
```

what you're really saying is that you depend on the other task having run first. So I would end up changing the name of that, though that's probably just a sample/throwaway name for this question. But, I digress and I'll continue calling the task `:callback` as written for this answer.

---

The main issue here is that when you call `execute` on a rake task, only that task gets executed. This is because there may be situations where you don't want or need to call the entire dependency chain. Let's say we add another task to your file:

```
desc "secondary task"
task :secondary do
  @greeting = 'Goodbye, Cruel World'

  Rake::Task['rspec_before:main'].execute
end
```

If we run this, we very likely want the `main` task to output `Goodbye, Cruel World`, instead of `Hello, World` and if we call all the dependencies, `main` would end up calling `:callback` which would override our `@greeting` and end up outputting `Hello, World`.

There is, however, another task that does call the entire dependency chain: `invoke`:

```
desc "secondary task"
task :secondary do
  @greeting = 'Goodbye, Cruel World'
  Rake::Task['rspec_before:main'].invoke
end
```

if we run this task, now we'll see `Hello, World` instead of `Goodbye, Cruel World`. So, having said all of this, what does that mean for your `RSpec` test? You simply need to change your `subject` to:

```
subject { @rake['rspec_before:main'].invoke }
```

because you are wanting to run the dependencies.